# Spring Converter is not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a converter, but it is not called. I Always get a BindException.

```
public class IntegerToQueConverter implements Converter<Integer, QuestionType> {

@Autowired
private QuestionTypeService questionTypeService;

@Override
public QuestionType convert(Integer questionType) {

    return questionTypeService.findOne(questionType);
}
```

I defined the following bean in application context.

```
<annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">

 <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" >
  <property name="converters">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.hr.quiz.converter.IntegerToQueConverter"/>

    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

update:

I want the converter to be called in this code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/insertQuestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView insertQuestion(@ModelAttribute("questions") Question question)
{
    ModelAndView view=new ModelAndView("addQuestion");

    System.out.println(question.getQuestion());


            .............................

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Are you using this in a web application?  Generally, you convert from String to a specific object type.

Comment: @KevinBowersox: yes.iam using this in a web application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type arguments of the `Converter` to `<String,QuestionType>`:

```
public class IntegerToQueConverter implements Converter<String, QuestionType> {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionTypeService questionTypeService;

    @Override
    public QuestionType convert(String questionType) {
        return questionTypeService.findOne(questionType);
    }
}
```

The values passed in with the request will be of type `String` which requires the converter to be of type `Converter<String,QuestionType>`.